# cannot run emulator in android studio and in genymotion

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

I was installed android studio, and when I Run my first App I found this note "your CPU doesn't support Vt-x"
so I can't run my App

when I used new images instead of an x86, my App is Run But the emulator Start and close very fast by himself, the screen of the emulator closed very quickly
what is wrong?

also, I try to run with 'Genymotion', also it doesn't Run, still with the white Screen-like image below
please help me, I would Run my Android emulator how?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

VT-x is known as virtualization hardware extensions in BIOS.

This is the security issue handled from BIOS. You just need to enable the VT-X from BIOS of your computer. Instead you have nothing to do from android studio or genymotion.

You can see this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/22915/how-do-i-enable-vt-x).

You can also check the way of doing such thing from [this blog](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Virtualization_Guide/sect-Virtualization-Troubleshooting-Enabling_Intel_VT_and_AMD_V_virtualization_hardware_extensions_in_BIOS.html), though this steps may vary in your BIOS.

Comment: my laptop is Dell Inspiron 1545, and I didn't find any option on Bios for virtualization, you know how I can be founded and enabled?

Comment: You may get your answer in this answer :
http://serverfault.com/questions/29602/how-to-enable-vt-extensions-on-a-dell-inspiron-1545